# Ember route communication with unrelated component

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-components

I know EmberJS promotes "data down, actions up", but I have a scenario that I'm not sure how to fit into that paradigm. It's best if I explain by an example that's analogous to what I'm trying to achieve.

Let's say I have a fixed header component ('`fixed-header`'). I want this header to appear always, so of course I add it to my main application template:

```
{{fixed-header}}
{{outlet}}
```

Now let's say I want my header to display some information about the route I'm on. For simplicity's sake, let's say each route has a title I want displayed in the fixed header. So whether I'm on `/foo` or `/foo/bar/baz` or `/wackawacka/meh?cat=meow`, I want that route to be able to send some data to `fixed-header` component to display. In other words, I kinda want to go against "data down" and do a "data up".

What is the ideal way to approach this? My first instinct was to create a service that `my-header` listens to and routes can post their information to. But is that the right thing to do? It seems weird to me to create a service just to send a little bit of text. Is there another way?

Comment: Honestly I think a service is perfect for that. Actually someday we will hopefully have an routing service for that.

Comment: Okay, I just thought it was overkill to have a service just for this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a parameter for your component.

```
{{fixed-header info=headerInfo}}
{{outlet}}
```

And then in any route in some hook

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  var headerInfo = ...
  this.controllerFor('application').set('headerInfo', headerInfo);
}
```

Comment: I actually like this solution. I was hesitant to use a service because I only needed to send a small text string to a component, and a service just seemed like overkill. I still might use a service if I decide I need to send more data, but for now, your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Service is the way to go. refer [Service Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/applications/services/)

> An Ember.Service is an Ember object that lives for the duration of the application, and can be made available in different parts of your application.
>   Services are useful for features that require **shared state** or persistent connections.